# How to reset opacity/animation with Jquery. jsfiddle included

Tags: jquery

I have these divs I want to fade out on mouseover and fade in on mouseout. 
Now when i hover fast over the Divs it starts to get buggy. It's fadein out and fading in and fading out when I left the div for quiet awhile. 
How can I get this less buggy and not make it to do fade out once I leave a div?

I tried the .stop with no luck.

```
$('#interieurprojecten, #interieurontwerpen, #interieurprojecten, #keukens, #kastenwanden, #meubels, #bedrijven').mouseover(function() {$(this).fadeTo( "slow" , 0.6, function() {});});
$('#interieurprojecten, #interieurontwerpen, #interieurprojecten, #keukens, #kastenwanden, #meubels, #bedrijven').mouseout(function() {$(this).fadeTo( "slow" , 1.0, function() {});});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/v21scmxu/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`.clearQueue()`](http://api.jquery.com/clearQueue/) before `.fadeTo`

http://jsfiddle.net/v21scmxu/1/

Comment: You can validate the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
$('#interieurprojecten, #interieurontwerpen, #interieurprojecten, #keukens, #kastenwanden, #meubels, #bedrijven')
.mouseover(function() {
    $(this).stop().fadeTo("slow", 0.6);
})
.mouseout(function() {
    $(this).stop().fadeTo("slow", 1.0)
;});
```

You were right to try `stop()`, but I guess you did something wrong.  Also, you appear to have had the `mouseout` handler inside the `mouseover` handler.  The above code has fixed that too.

Here's an updated jsFiddle...

http://jsfiddle.net/v21scmxu/2/

Comment: No problem - glad you got it sorted :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `stop( true, true )` [stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)

```
$('#interieurprojecten, #interieurontwerpen, #interieurprojecten, #keukens, #kastenwanden, #meubels, #bedrijven')
    .mouseover(function () {
    $(this).stop( true, true ).fadeTo("slow", 0.6, function () {});
});
$('#interieurprojecten, #interieurontwerpen, #interieurprojecten, #keukens, #kastenwanden, #meubels, #bedrijven').mouseout(function () {
    $(this).stop( true, true ).fadeTo("slow", 1.0, function () {});
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hamix/8vcyz6fr/1/)